# Question about $ \int_{-1}^{0}\sum_{n=1}^{x}n^sdx=\zeta (-s) \forall s\in \Bbb N$

Tags: calculus, number-theory, summation, zeta-functions, bernoulli-numbers

what I found from messing around was 
$$
\int_{-1}^{0}\sum_{n=1}^{x}n^sdx=\zeta (-s)
$$
$$
s\in \mathbb{N}
$$
when the partial sum is changed to an equivalent polynomial using Faulhaber's formula.

For example 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{x}n^3 = \frac{x^2(x+1)^2}{4}
$$
and 
$$
\int_{-1}^{0}\frac{x^2(x+1)^2}{4}dx = \frac{1}{120} = \zeta(-3)
$$ 
This is pretty much my first time in the realm of the zeta function, so i wasn't sure if this was obvious, or a given thing. But I couldn't find any reference to it online.
What I'm asking is why this is and what I should search for if I want to learn more about this.

Comment: i changed the title to latex to make it readable. is it ok now?

Comment: the sum $\sum_{n=1}^x f(n)$ is meaningless if $x\notin\Bbb N$. I mean you want to define the analytic continuation of $f(n;s):=\sum_{k=1}^n k^s$ when you set $n\in\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 7):

This can be proven using a couple of bits from the internet; use [Faulhaber's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) to define the polynomial:
$$\sum _{k=1}^{x}{k}^{p}={\frac {\sum _{j=0}^{p} \left( -1 \right) ^{j}{
p+1\choose j}B_j {x}^{p+1-j}}{p+1}}$$
then integrate to get:
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \int _
{-1}^{0}\!{\frac {\sum _{j=0}^{p} \left( -1 \right) ^{j}{p+1\choose j}
B_j {x}^{p+1-j}}{p+1}}{dx}&=-\left( -1 \right) ^{p}\frac{1}{p+1}\sum _{j=0}^{p}{\frac {{p+1\choose j}B_j }{p+2-j}},\\
&=-\left( -1 \right) ^{p}{\frac {B_{p+1}
}{p+1}},\\
&=\zeta(-p)
\end{aligned} $$
where we have used the [recursion relation for Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number) to pass from the first to the second line and [the known value of the zeta function at negative integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function)  for the last line. The $(-1)^p$ is trivial for most $p$ as even order Bernoulli numbers are zero but the zeroth order is not so we must keep it for that case.