# Is there any intuition behind why $\zeta(-1) = \int_{-1}^{0} \frac{N(N+1)}{2}$?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Question: Is there any reason why the following happens to be true: 
$$\int_{-1}^{0} \frac{N(N+1)}{2} dN = \zeta(-1)$$

Here are some Facts:

- If you compute $\sum_{i=1}^{N}i = \frac{N(N+1)}{2}$
- $\int_{-1}^0 \frac{N(N+1)}{2} dN = -\frac{1}{12}$
- for $s>1, \zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{s}}$
- If you naively plug in $s=-1$ to the above, this is exactly $
  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n$
- $\zeta(-1)=\frac{-1}{12}$
- The $N$th partial sum of this is exactly $\frac{N(N+1)}{2}$

Note this is **not** a question asking why $\zeta(-1)=\frac{-1}{12}$.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/725004/question-about-int-10-sum-n-1xnsdx-zeta-s-forall-s-in-bbb-n?rq=1

Comment: No, I had not. Thanks for the reference! I will read through it and answer my own question.  :-)